# Smart gwt hint in field styling

Tags: css, gwt, smartgwt

**My code:**

```
myTextItem = new TextItem();
myTextItem.setHint("Some text");
myTextItem.setShowHintInField(true);
myTextItem.setHintStyle("myTextItemHint");
```

**My css:**

```
.myTextItemHint {
   color: gray;
}
```

**My Problem:**

My issue is that I can have that `setShowHintInField(true)` set OR my css getting applied, but not both.

I found more info about this on the link: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=14463 but I cannot come up with a common style / place for it, that would make the trick while the hint is inside the field.

**My question:**

What kind of css would I need in this case and how I tell the field to use it?

**What I have tried:**

With that `setShowHintInField(true)` line and without. Both cases: half of the solution is there. Not both halves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormItem` has method [`setCellStyle()`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setCellStyle%28java.lang.String%29) to set the style of specific cell.

Use

```
myTextItem.setCellStyle("myTextItemHint");
```

your CSS will look like this:

```
.myTextItemHint, .myTextItemHint input {
    color: gray;
}
```

Override other properties also if needed

```
.textItem,.textItemFocused,.textItemDisabled,.textItemDisabledHint,.textItemError,.textItemHint
```

For more information on CSS, Please have a look at `skin_styles.css` that is already shipped along with standard skins in SmartGWT.

Comment: Are these extras needed, 'cause it seems to work also without? And how I apply that longish list (example of one, please)?

Comment: Not at all but if you want different style to be applied on disabled `TextItem` or different style when focused, when there is any error etc.

Comment: Missed that 'if needed'.

Comment: I needed to add also a `KeyUpHandler` to check if value is not `null` and apply different style when not `null`. That way I could prevent manually the given value from coming gray.

Comment: I think focus/blur listeners are more accurate in this case rather than setting style name on each key up handler.

Comment: blur events fire quite randomly, every losing of focus does not trigger event. Sometimes you just cannot obey good principles, if they don't work.

Comment: Is it a known bug in GWT?